# Moshe doubts G-d in Numbers 20:8

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, water, speech-talking, chukas

In Numbers 20:8 G-d commands Moshe to speak to the inanimate rock for water.

Was this really a reasonable command for G-d to make?

Even Moshe seems to have thought this was an impossible accomplishment.

Is there any way in which we can understand why G-d would want Moshe to speak to a non-living thing such as a rock?

Comment: The word 'el' ('to') is probably meant as 'al' ('regarding'), as is the case elsewhere in the Bible (from Rav Yitzchak Etshalom). Thus, the command would mean, "Speak (to the nation) regarding the rock (and the miracle about to be wrought from it).

Comment: It would be inconceivable that G-d would command Moses to publicly ask-- read 'pray to'-- an inanimate object for water. It would only open the floodgates for idolatry.

Comment: At least some commentaries understand it as teaching Torah by the rock (citation needed)

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot Would he have been asking or commanding?

Comment: @Ephraim one is spelled with an aleph and one would be spelled with an ayin. Also, who would Moshe be taking to about the rock? Klal Yisroel?  Than the next word li'eineihem makes no sense. Try again.

Comment: "Was this really a reasonable command for G-d to make?" Why not, if it was miraculous? Or are you assuming it was a natural event that Moses somehow caused?

Comment: Is talking to a rock less reasonable than expecting it to give water? Does a rock have more of a spout to give water than an ear to hear words?

Comment: @user6591 Yes, they are spelled with different letters. That doesn't preclude my point- Chazal, for example, on 'Vayedaber al Ha'Eitzim', emended to 'Vayedaber el Ha'Eitzim' (with Shlomo).

Comment: @ephraim That is called a drasha. Even if we are allowed to decide what pashut pshat is, we do not get to make up drashos. And then convince ourselves that is the only logical approach.

Comment: @user6591 There are also real pshat examples-- that was just the one I remembered off-hand. Give me a few minutes-- sorry for the previous tone.

Comment: @ephraim please forgive mine! Unfortunately i find people prove themselves better when pushed, sometimes they get upset when i push them. I'm willing to accept such a pshat it just seems so foreign that i would need something solid for it to rest on. Push push:)

Comment: Your assertions are probably correct. Food for thought :)

Comment: I'm assuming that your reasoning in your 3rd par. that Moshe thought it was impossible is based on how you interpreted Moshe saying to the people, "Hear you rebels, Can we bring forth water from this rock?" I think common interpretation suggests that Moshe spoke sarcastically, in a sense.

Answer (score 2):

In his commentary to that Numbers (20:8), Rav Sa'adyah Gaon renders "אל הסלע" as "על הסלע". (according to R. Yosef Qafih's Hebrew translation of R. Sa'adyah's Arabic.) In his notes there, R. Yosef Qafih explains that the intent was not that Moshe should speak to the stone, but rather that he should speak *to the Jews* in the proximity of the stone. Specifically, (R. Qafih explains in his notes to Rav Sa'adyah Gaon's explanation to verse 12), he was to speak to them about the infinity ability of God. The intent of the later verse (20:12) is not that Moshe did not believe in God, but that he did not inspire faith in God on the part of the Jews.

The Tanchuma (quoted by Rashi to verse 11), however, understand that Moshe was meant to talk *to* the rock. This does not seems so difficult as it is no less likely to cause water then hitting it.

Comment: I feel that Rav Saadya Gaon addresses the issues very well. If that is unacceptable, or if there is something about the explanation of Chazal that remains unacceptable, please specify.

Comment: +1 This is a great source even though i don't think it makes sense and doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: @user6591 I am waiting for more input from the OP to know whether or not it answers the question, ir if a different angle is desired.